# model conditional constraint in Gurobi

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I am trying to model a conditional constraint in Guuobi python:

***if a>= b then c == 1, otherwise c == 0***

***a and c are both model variables and c is binary***

I have the following code based on [How do I model conditional statements in Gurobi?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414392016529-How-do-I-model-conditional-statements-in-Gurobi-)but something is not correct as I cannot obtain the optimal answer. My code is:

```
Constraint4 = LP.addConstrs((a[i,j] >= b[j] + eps - M * (1 - c[i,j])
                             for j in items
                             for i in months
                             if i == months[2]), name="BigM1")

Constraint5 = LP.addConstrs((a[i,j] <= b[j] + M * c[i,j]
                             for j in items
                             for i in months
                             if i == months[2]), name="BigM2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing index of b. It should be also index to j.

```
Constraint4 = LP.addConstrs((a[i,j] >= b[i,j] + eps - M * (1 - c[i,j])
                             for j in items
                             for i in months
                             if i == months[2]), name="BigM1")

Constraint5 = LP.addConstrs((a[i,j] <= b[i, j] + M * c[i,j]
                             for j in items
                             for i in months
                             if i == months[2]), name="BigM2")
```